# Scala Future/Option for comprehension issues

Tags: scala, monads, monad-transformers, scala-cats, for-comprehension

I am trying to write a function that reads from a repository (which returns `F[Option[Entry]]` where `F` is a future) and then converts it to `F[Option[Element]]`. The function `convert()` takes a `Seq[Entry]` and returns `ValidatedNel[LoadError, Seq[Element]]`. I am trying to do this with for comprehensions however my issue is that the function returns `F[Opt[F[Seq[Element]]]]` instead of `F[Opt[Element]]`. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be great!

Note: ValidatedNel is a cats datatype

```
override def findByPath(key: String)(
  implicit ME: MonadError[F, Throwable]
): F[Option[Element]] = {
  val result = for {
    optionEntry <- repo.findByKey(key)
  } yield for {
    entry <- optionEntry
    elements = convert(Seq(entry))
  } yield elements.fold(
    reason => ME.raiseError[Seq[Element]](ClientError(reason)),
    ME.pure
  )
  result
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use monad transformer `OptionT` and unpack head of `Element` sequence (since you pack a single `Entry` into sequence)

```
override def findByPath(key: String)(
  implicit ME: MonadError[F, Throwable]
): F[Option[Element]] = {
  val result = for {
    entry <- OptionT(repo.findByKey(key))
    elements = convert(Seq(entry))
    res <- OptionT.liftF(elements.fold(
      reason => ME.raiseError[Element](ClientError(reason)),
      elems => ME.pure(elems.head)
    ))
  } yield res

  result.value
}
```